# How to calculate $E(e^{XY})$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

How to calculate the expected value  $E(e^{XY})$, $X\sim N(0,1)$, $Y\sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent?

I understand how to calculate $E(e^{X})$ and $E(e^{Y})$ but I have no clue how to do $E(e^{XY})$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: yes they are independent

Answer (score 0):

Assuming independence you can easily find the distribution of $Z=e^{XY}$

$$ e^{XY} =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \frac{1}{2} \\
e^X, & \frac{1}{2} 
\end{cases}$$

This rv takes the value $1$ with probability 0.5 and it is a Lognormal  with probability 0.5...the resulting rv is not absolutely continuous

I think you can conclude by yourself